# link feature - Azure SQL Managed Instance multiple databases

Tags: azure-sql-managed-instance

Is it possible to replicate two databases in the same DAG to an Azure MI?

Or is it possible to configure two DAG (single db) pointing to the same Azure SQL MI?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/managed-instance-link-feature-overview?view=azuresql#limitations

Comment: why do you think there is a limitation to just one database in a DAG and Link feature ?

Comment: In the configuration limitation I read this:
"Only one database can be placed into a single availability group for one Managed Instance link. However, it's possible to replicate multiple databases in a single SQL Server instance by establishing multiple links." but it is unclear for me